# SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR: relation while synchronizing entity changes in API Platfrom

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I am creating entities in the API Platform. Everytime I add a new entity or modify a field I run

```
docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

to synchronize the schema. I faced no problems this far but after I created a datetime field and tried synchronizing I get a table already exists error

```
In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 66:
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE SEQUENCE financial_statement_templates_definition_fstemplate_definition_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1':  

In PDOConnection.php line 83:
SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "financial_statement_templates_definition_fstemplate_definition_" already exists  

In PDOConnection.php line 78:
SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "financial_statement_templates_definition_fstemplate_definition_" already exists
```

In the normal case I would have just dropped the tables and recreated it but since I am using the API Platform within docker I have no access to the database. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out. I dropped the database by running the following command

```
docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
```

Then recreated the database using this statement from the command line

```
docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

Then updated the schema using this statement

```
docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Updating database schema...

     6 queries were executed

     [OK] Database schema updated successfully!
```